# In Clickhouse is there a setting to control how column alias works?

Tags: clickhouse

I am trying to migrate an Athena query to run on Clickhouse. This query uses the CTE approach and has multiple table joins in it. But the column names returned by Athena and Clickhouse are different. Below is the sample query and the output returned by both Athena and Clickhouse:

`with T1 as ( SELECT * FROM ( SELECT id, path_id FROM table1 ) AS A LEFT JOIN ( SELECT id as userid, DPID FROM table2 ) AS B ON A.id = B.userid LEFT JOIN ( SELECT id as LPID FROM table3 ) AS C ON A.path_id = C.LPID LEFT JOIN ( SELECT _id FROM table4 ) AS D ON B.DPID = D._id WHERE  DPID is not null ) select * from T1`

`Athena Columns: id, path_id, userid, DPID, LPID, _id`

while Clickhouse returns the column names as

`A.id, A.path_id, B.userid, B.DPID, C.LPID, D._id`

Is there any existing setting in Clickhouse which can help control how the alias names are referenced?

I did try the "asterisk_include_alias_columns" and "prefer_column_name_to_alias" but that didn't help.

Thanks in advance.